# Laravel scheduler not working

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5, scheduler

I have a Laravel 5 application where i want to run cronjobs, i have created a command, that will be running every 5 minutes.

But for some reason it´s never called.

I have added the following crontab.

```
*   *   *   *   *   php /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run
```

I checked the cron log file, and it looks like it´s running:

```
Apr 15 10:19:01 lvps92-51-xx-xx CROND[15420]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run)
```

But it is never calling the command.
The funny thing is that if i run the command manually its working...

```
[root@lvps92-51-xx-xx /]# php /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run    
Running scheduled command: (touch /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/storage/framework/schedule-c56ad4a76ba9d8e31def649e20c42f73; /usr/local/php566-cgi/bin/php artisan test:run; 
rm /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/storage/framework/schedule-c56ad4a76ba9d8e31def649e20c42f73) > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

There is no logging entries in the Laravel Log.

(I know that i run the cronjob as root, but that was to avoid permissions errors doing testing)

Laravel version: 5.0.27
Server: Centos 6

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, i have more than 1 PHP version installed and for some reason cron is using the default php installation even when i have added the new PHP path to .bash_profile.

I fixed it by adding path to the right PHP version:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/php566-cgi/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

That way its forced to run with that PHP version.

Comment: Can you share what makes the he two PHP version cause the `schedule:run` not to run?

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem few days ago and this is how I solved it.
I am actually using hostmonster for hosting my application.
My cron job runs every minutes.

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope this helps